# Multiplication of numbers that have sizes greater than a 64-bit register

Tags: 64-bit, multiplication

For a 64-bit processor, the size of registers are 64 bits. So the maximum bits that can be multiplied together at a time are: a 32 bit number by a 32 bit number.
Is this true or are there any other factors that determine the number of bits multiplied by each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can not say that.

That depends on how the algorithm of multiplication is designed.
Think about that:

```
x * y = x + x + x + ... + x        // y times
```

You can think of every multiplication as a sum of additions.

Adding a number to another one is not a thing of registers because you add always two figurs, save the result and the carry-over and go on to the next two figurs till you added the two numbers.

This way you can multiply very long numbers with a very small register but a large memory to save the result.

Comment: So if I multiply 128 bit numbers together using a C code or python, and try to see how much time it takes, it will be totally fine.

Comment: @TasneemGhunaim Will surely take some time, but it is possible. Yes.

Comment: @TasneemGhunaim If this answer was helpful for you please consider upvoting it. Thx.